# What does `workbench.action.terminal.switchTerminal` do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Tried this command, seems to be doing nothing , does anyone know the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now been [removed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128215) from the command palette:

> Thanks for the report and for digging into this stuff . This command isn't meant to be exposed in the command palette as its only purpose is to drive the terminal dropdown behind the scenes.

---

There was [a bug caused by this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116098) action that prevented users from pasting into a terminal since the key binding for pasting was set to this command as well as the paste command - so I am wondering as part of the fix for the pasting issue, they've made this command in the meantime not work.

Another user [couldn't tell what this action does either](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116331#issuecomment-778013657) and I can't myself. Perhaps that is why the default settings for it are unbound.